# I Need Help Creating An Image On A Canvas With Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I`m trying to paste an image in Tkinter with the code below.

But, whenever i try to paste an image nothing shows up.

```
from Tkinter import *

m = Tk()
c = Canvas(m)

def pp(event):
 x = event.x + 50
 y = event.y + 50
 t = PhotoImage('a.jpeg')
 c.create_image(x,y,image=t)

 m.bind('<B1-Motion>', pp)
 m.mainloop()
```

Could someone show me what i`m doing wrong

Comment: You can only use .gif images with photo image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the .jpeg into a .gif image. Tkinter only supports gif images. If you don't know how use a program like [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org) to do it or an online app.